# How to get the nth positional argument in bash?

Tags: bash, arguments, command-line-arguments

How to get the `n`th positional argument in Bash, where `n` is variable?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Use Bash's indirection feature:

```
#!/bin/bash
n=3
echo ${!n}
```

Running that file:

```
$ ./ind apple banana cantaloupe dates
```

Produces:

```
cantaloupe
```

**Edit:**

You can also do array slicing:

```
echo ${@:$n:1}
```

but not array subscripts:

```
echo ${@[n]}  #  WON'T WORK
```

Comment: @AlexanderOleynikov It causes a "bad substitution" error; I assume because `@` (and `*`) are "Special Parameters" and because they are not valid array names? `${@}` *does* refer to the numbered parameters, but `@` is not an array and support is not implemented to parse it as such, whereas e.g. "`${unsetvariable}`" would produce empty output because it is a valid array/variable name, just not set yet (and these exceptions are specially handled in bash's source code, I guess). I tried to find a better reason in `man bash`, but scanning for @'s made me run out of patience. ;P

Comment: In zsh, the last option works (because why wouldn't it).

Answer (score 13):

If `N` is saved in a variable, use

```
eval echo \${$N}
```

if it's a constant use

```
echo ${12}
```

since

```
echo $12
```

does not mean the same!

Comment: What's the difference between `${12}` and `$12`?

Comment: Hi @HelloGoodbye, `$12` means `$1` and the character `2`. `${12}` means the 12th parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Read

[Handling positional parameters](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams)

and

[Parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)

$0: the first positional parameter

$1 ... $9: the argument list elements from 1 to 9

Comment: This answer does not address OP's original question. He specifically asked how to get a parameter by its index stored in a variable.

Answer (score -2):

If you are trying to get specifically nth field or the last field in specific the simplest way is by

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
echo ${@:${#}}
```

output

```
sh 5.1$ sh nth_field.sh 1 23 1000 103399
103399
```