# BASH scripting: n-th parameter of $@ when the index is a variable?

Tags: bash, shell, argv

I want to retrieve the n-th parameter of $@ (the list of command line parameters passed to the script), where n is stored in a variable.

I tried ${$n}.

For example, I want to get the 2nd command line parameter of an invocation:

```
./my_script.sh alpha beta gamma
```

And the index should not be explicit but stored in a variable n.

Sourcecode:

```
n=2
echo ${$n}
```

I would expect the output to be "beta", but I get the error:

```
./my_script.sh: line 2: ${$n}: bad substitution
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a duplicate. Same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497811/how-to-get-the-nth-positional-argument-in-bash

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
args=("$@")
echo ${args[1]}
```

okay replace the "1" with some $n or something...

Answer (score 40):

You can use *variable indirection*. It is independent of arrays, and works fine in your example:

```
n=2
echo "${!n}"
```

**Edit:** *Variable Indirection* can be used in a lot of situations. If there is a variable `foobar`, then the following two variable expansions produce the same result:

```
$foobar

name=foobar
${!name}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure this works too but I do not understand why. Why "nothing to do with arrays"?! Isn't $@ a list (not an array)?

Comment: @gojira I think the point nosid is making is that you don't even need to copy the list of arguments separately, and could just reference it by using variable indirection

Comment: @gojira: `$@` is array-like. The expression `${!n}` in this answer is interpreted as `$2` when `n` is 2.

Answer (score 12):

The following works too:

```
#!/bin/bash
n=2
echo ${@:$n:1}
```

Comment: The dollar sign before the n can be omitted.

Answer (score 5):

The portable (non-bash specific) solution is

```
$ set a b c d
$ n=2
$ eval echo \${$n}
b
```

Comment: @gojira: You should be aware of the [security implications](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

Answer (score 2):

`eval` can help you access the variable indirectly, which means evaluate the expression twice.

You can do like this `eval alph=\$$n; echo $alph`