# Get the next element in $@

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to parse args like I do in C:

```c
if (str[i] == something && str[i + 1] == something) {
      //do somthing
}
```

I can't figure out how to do the `str[i + 1]`. Here's what I tried:

```sh
for a in $@ ; do
        if [ $a == "create" ] && [sed 's/table/']; then
            echo "create database"
        fi
done
```

I'm trying to to something if I find `create` and right after `create` if there's `database`.

Comment: See [BASH scripting: n-th parameter of $@ when the index is a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10749976/4154375), [How to get the nth positional argument in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1497811/4154375), and [Accessing shell script arguments by index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16916281/4154375).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash, we can use indirect variables to do the same thing:

```sh
for ((i = 1, j = 2; i < $#; i++, j++)); do
    if [[ ${!i} == "create" && ${!j} == "database" ]]; then
        echo "create database"
        break
    fi
done
```

This technique does not *consume* the arguments like `shift` does.

Ref: 4th paragraph of [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

---

A couple of points about your code:

```sh
for a in $@ ; do
        if [ $a == "create" ] && [sed 's/table/']; then
            echo "create database"
        fi
done
```

1. Always quote `"$@"` -- that's the only way to keep `"arguments with whitespace"` together.
2. in bash, use `[[...]]` instead of `[...]` -- the double bracket form is more safe regarding unquoted variables.
3. the brackets are not mere syntax, `[` is a **command**. For external commands, don't use brackets:

   ```sh
   if [[ $a == "create" ]] && sed 's/table/other/' some_file; then
   ```

   Carefully read `help if` at a bash prompt.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in a loop with a flag, but the usual way to do this sort of thing is to shift arguments as you consume them.  Something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

while test $# -gt 0; do
    case $1 in
    create) shift; echo "arg after create is '$1'";;
    # ...
    esac
    shift
done
```

Comment: Or, you can change the order and refer to the argument as `$2`, delaying the shift until after you've used it.

Answer (score 0):

You may call it cheating, but you could put $@ into an array `str` initially:

```
str=( "$@" )
i=... # Whatever you need
if [[ ${str[$i]} == something && ${str[$((i+1))]} == something ]]
then
  ....
```

This comes closest. However, in practice it is often more convenient to reconsider your algorithm, rather than to bend a language to make it look similar to a language you are already familiar with.

Comment: yeah i reconsidered it thanks tho !