# Linux Bash: how to put value of $var into "$" to make it $($var) with $var bigger than 9?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, eval

I need to <kbd>$</kbd> be a function of variable <kbd>$a</kbd>, so <kbd>$($a)</kbd> would be equal <kbd>$value_of_a</kbd> (so there would be possible to print OPTIONS of a command under number "a").

> For example: if <kbd>a=5</kbd> I need that bash make a call to the <kbd>$5</kbd> (<kbd>$5</kbd> is the OPTION5 that was when the program was typed into the Terminal; for example in

```
./hello.sh qq ww ee rr tt
```

> the "tt" is the option №5), so I need

```bash
echo $5
```

> but I don't know how to make it work through <kbd>a</kbd> and not through typing <kbd>$5</kbd> manually

I've tried something like this

```bash
"${$a}"
```

this

```bash
"${0+$a}"
```

and later on even found <kbd>eval</kbd>:

```bash
eval b=( '$'"$a" )
```

so calling <kbd>$b</kbd> places in <kbd>$b</kbd>'s place "<kbd>$-->value_of_a_here<--</kbd>"

but <kbd>eval</kbd> gives only first digit, so if <kbd>a=11</kbd> then <kbd>$b</kbd> prints OPTION1|1, as it would be <kbd>$1</kbd> (with adding <kbd>1</kbd> as a string) and not <kbd>$11</kbd>.

> So if there would be

```bash
./hello.sh q w e r t y u i o p g
a=11
eval b=( '$'"$a" )
echo $b
```

> then output would be

```
q1
```

> and not the

```
g
```

It seems that bigger that <kbd>$9</kbd> one can't make it at all. Is it possible? (and I heard that 1 line of a command with its sending OPTIONS is limited by 32 bytes, or something about so; maybe it is here?)

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [use braces](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Positional-Parameters.html) to access positional parameters above 9.

Also, bash uses special syntax for [indirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
$ set -- q w e r t y u i o p g
$ echo $11
q1
$ echo ${11}
g
$ a=11
$ echo $a
11
$ echo ${$a}
bash: ${$a}: bad substitution
$ echo ${!a}
g
$
```

---

The 32 byte limit you read about may be referring to the "bang path". I can't currently find the definitive reference but the [Perl documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun) states:

> historically some operating systems silently chopped off kernel interpretation of the `#!` line after 32 characters

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1497811/10971581 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006